# Include a specific cell in an array query Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have an array query that runs across multiple sheets in a Google Doc. The query works fine, but I would like to know the sheet of each data returned. I made an example [HERE](https://docs.google.com/a/rbe.sk.ca/spreadsheets/d/1A7UJxOK0SCNwwrEPo__XfEO7_LUdCsmfmm9dkzmB0fU/edit?usp=sharing) . the formula is :
`=QUERY({Sheet2!A2:B6; Sheet3!A2:B6}, "select Col1, Col2 where Col2 = 'Y'")`

When a 'Y' is found, I want to return the Data in Col1, Col2 AND (this is the part I don't know how to do)  the value of A1 on the page where the match occured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert page title in the array as its third column, and select that column with the query:

```
=arrayformula(query({Sheet2!A2:B6, iferror(Sheet2!A2:A6/0, Sheet2!A1); Sheet3!A2:B6, iferror(Sheet3!A2:A6/0, Sheet3!A1)}, "select Col1, Col2, Col3 where Col2 = 'Y'"))
```

Here, `iferror(Sheet2!A2:A6/0, Sheet2!A1)` is a clumsy but effective way of saying: take the shape of array `Sheet2!A2:A6/0` and fill it with the content of the cell Sheet2!A1. This results in the page title being repeated in every row taken from that sheet (provided that `arrayformula` wrapper is present, so that the computation `/0` is performed with the array). The query returns

```
Data 2 on page 2    Y   Page 2 Title
Data 4 on page 2    Y   Page 2 Title
Data 2 on page 3    Y   Page 3 Title
```